# How to get the number of posts in a selected category?

Tags: posts, categories

I would like to show the number of posts on the category page. How is it possible? I tried to find a solution but no luck..

Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

If you are on a category archive you don't need to query all the posts of the category like Christopher Ross suggested and you can't use `get_the_category()` like Max Yudin suggested unless you are already in the loop.

What you can do is simply get the current category object using `get_queried_object()` which will hold the post count, ex:

```
$category = get_queried_object();
echo $category->count;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$category = get_the_category(); 
echo $category[0]->category_count;
```

See [/Function_Reference/get_the_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)

Comment: `get_the_category()` is only available when you are in the loop

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the category page(archive) just use:

```
$cat= get_the_category();
echo $cat[0]->count;
```

This works on looping as well.  But if you want to show the category count of a specific category anywhere on the site. Use this function:

```
function wt_get_category_count($catID) {
        global $wpdb;           
            $SQL = "SELECT $wpdb->term_taxonomy.count FROM $wpdb->terms, $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE $wpdb->terms.term_id=$wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id=$catID";             
            return $wpdb->get_var($SQL);
    }
    echo wt_get_category_count(2);
```