# How to hide widget if current category has no posts assigned to it?

Tags: widgets

I'm using the following code and the Widget Logic plugin to dynamically display or hide a widget on category pages:

```
$thiscat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$parent = $thiscat->category_parent;
return
!(is_page( ) || (is_category( ) && empty ($parent) ) );
```

I would like to add a further condition to this that checks whether or not the current category has any posts assigned to it. If not, then don't display the widget.

I tried using `category_count;`. but couldn't get it to work. Here's the complete code I tried:

```
$thiscat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$parent = $thiscat->category_parent;
$postcount = $thiscat->category_count;
return
!(is_page( ) || (is_category( ) && empty ($parent) && $postcount > 0 ) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be you're using the category on a custom post type, in that case `category_count` won't include those. There's another handy value on the `$category`-object however: [`$category->count`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84992/how-to-get-the-number-of-posts-in-a-selected-category). Try replacing this:

```
$postcount = $thiscat->category_count;
```

with this

```
$postcount = $thiscat->count;
```

> The count attribute includes custom post types as well if the custom post type uses standard categories.[<sup>1</sup>](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but still can't get it to work. I think it might be a problem with the syntax.

Comment: This is what I tried:

`$thiscat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$parent = $thiscat->category_parent;
$postcount = $thiscat->count;
 return
 !(is_page( ) || (is_category( ) && empty ($parent) && $postcount > 0 ) );`

Comment: It turns out I don't need `!is_page()` as the widget is for displaying posts and I'm not even sure why I had that in the code. I also decided I don't need `empty ($parent)` either as the parent categories don't have any posts assigned to them. 

So, this is what I'm left with:

`$thiscat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) ); $postcount = $thiscat->count; return $postcount > 0;`

Comment: @jrcollins Nice, glad it worked out! :)